# IE9 Mobile - html5 video events?

Tags: html, events, video, ie-mobile

Doesn't IE9 Mobile support html5 video events?

till now i got no luck with that ... and also found no information about it.

any ideas ? ;)

thx!

Answer (score 0):

it seems to only support a very, very minimal subset of what desktop ie9 can handle. So far from what I observed, ie9mobile supports e.g. "loadstart" and "canplay" events but does not fire the "ended" event just like many others. Test with your phone here to see what's possible and what not: http://www.w3.org/2010/05/video/mediaevents.html